# How to import scss file in react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass

I've integrated a .ts file(component7.js) in my react-project in create-react-app and I've styled it using styles from .scss file and imported it. When I open my project in localhost, the stylings are vanished. Apparently the scss doesn't work. I've attached the two files Please anyone help me fix the issue.

component7.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./component7.module.scss";
//import  './component7.css';

const Component7 = ({
  janeDoe = "Jane Doe",
  student = "Student",
  details = "DETAILS",
  username = "Username :",
  emailAddress = "Email address :",
  password = "Password :",
  dateOfBirth = "Date of birth :",
  thunderBalance = "Thunder Balance :",
  num600 = "600",
  editDetails = "Edit Details"
}) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.component7}>
      <p className={styles.janeDoe}>{janeDoe}</p>
      <p className={styles.student}>{student}</p>
      <img
        alt=""
        className={styles.vector5}
        src="https://static.overlay-tech.com/assets/aa911a93-6f68-4cde-9fd6-ce8d7d43529d.svg"
      />
      <p className={styles.details}>{details}</p>
      <p className={styles.username}>{username}</p>
      <p className={styles.emailAddress}>{emailAddress}</p>
      <p className={styles.username}>{password}</p>
      <p className={styles.dateOfBirth}>{dateOfBirth}</p>
      <div className={styles.flexWrapperTwo}>
        <p className={styles.thunderBalance}>
          {thunderBalance}
        </p>
        <p className={styles.num600}>{num600}</p>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.flexWrapperOne}>
        <p className={styles.editDetails}>{editDetails}</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Component7;
```

component7.scss file:

```
.component7 {
  background-color: rgba(245, 246, 255, 1);
  border-radius: 50px 0px 0px;
  padding: 300px 42px 93px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.janeDoe {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 93px;
}
.student {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgba(149, 170, 255, 1);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: 109px;
}
.vector5 {
  margin-bottom: 52px;
}
.details {
  width: 104px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgba(150, 158, 179, 1);
  margin-bottom: 23px;
}
.username {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgba(150, 158, 179, 1);
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.emailAddress {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgba(150, 158, 179, 1);
  margin-bottom: 9px;
}
.dateOfBirth {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgba(150, 158, 179, 1);
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.flexWrapperTwo {
  margin-bottom: 64px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.thunderBalance {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgba(134, 133, 133, 1);
  margin-right: 9px;
}
.num600 {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgba(38, 24, 190, 1);
}
.flexWrapperOne {
  margin-left: 62px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 12px 22px 12px 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(
    288deg,
    rgba(28, 14, 185, 1) 1%,
    rgba(151, 153, 249, 1) 107%
  );
}
.editDetails {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

Comment: Are you using `webpack`? If you are then you need to install the `node-sass` module, and maybe `sass-loader`. If you aren't then you need to do something else to load the scss. `SCSS` needs to be converted to `css` somehow for the browser to read it, it can't be read by itself.

Comment: @Sam I've already installed node-sass

Comment: what happens when you additionally add `import "./component7.module.scss";`? This is the way i was doing in my react typescript projects

Comment: @Athii it says " Module not found: Can't resolve './component7.module.css' in 'C:\Users\Intel\Desktop\Disha\test\src "

Comment: @codelover does it at least loads the classnames into the DOM? You can see it in developer mode in your browser (F12)